# Show alert when link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show an alert when a link is clicked using jQuery like this..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
 $(".nav_link").click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="navlink" id="navlink1" href="#">
  Link 1
</a>
<a class="navlink" id="navlink2" href="#">
  Link 2
</a>
<a class="navlink" id="navlink3" href="#">
  Link 3
</a>
```

It isn't working for some reason, can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: typo here use `$(".navlink")` instead of `$(".nav_link")`.The class name is `navlink` not `nav_link`

Comment: _ is the problem use navlink no nav_link

Answer (score 1):

You don't have element with class name of `nav_link`. Use `navlink` instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navlink").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="navlink" id="navlink1" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="navlink" id="navlink2" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a class="navlink" id="navlink3" href="#">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".navlink").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
                alert('clicked');
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.nav_link` class selector in your jQuery selector while your tags have `navlink` class. you should change it to `navlink` like the following :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
 $(".navlink").click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="navlink" id="navlink1" href="#">
  Link 1
</a>
<a class="navlink" id="navlink2" href="#">
  Link 2
</a>
<a class="navlink" id="navlink3" href="#">
  Link 3
</a>
```

OR you should change your `a` tags classes from  `navlink` to `nav_link` like :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
 $(".nav_link").click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="nav_link" id="navlink1" href="#">
  Link 1
</a>
<a class="nav_link" id="navlink2" href="#">
  Link 2
</a>
<a class="nav_link" id="navlink3" href="#">
  Link 3
</a>
```

Comment: how did you bring the compilier into the edit screen

Comment: @nikhilsugandh what do you mean by compilier?

Comment: how do you make your code runnable in your ouptput RUN CODE SNIPPET

Comment: I just hit the `copy snippet to answer` of the question code snippet.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh also you can use code snippet  by pressing `ctrl+m` in your answer part.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for it:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
         </head>
      <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
          <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <script>
          
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".navlink").click(function(){
              alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
          }); 
           });
          </script>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           
           <a class="navlink" id="navlink1" href="#">
             Link 1
           </a>
           <a class="navlink" id="navlink2" href="#">
             Link 2
           </a>
           <a class="navlink" id="navlink3" href="#">
             Link 3
           </a>
        </body>
        </html>
        <script src="" async defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
     </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navlink").click(function(){
          alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
      }); 
       });
      </script>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <a class="navlink" id="navlink1" href="#">
         Link 1
       </a>
       <a class="navlink" id="navlink2" href="#">
         Link 2
       </a>
       <a class="navlink" id="navlink3" href="#">
         Link 3
       </a>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

check fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/e9Ljou4q/
hope that worked

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking on a link ie the anchor tag, which itself has a native handling whenever a click event is called upon the anchor tag. So, ***for making your click handling work you have to cancel the default handling by preventing the default behaviour of anchor tag for a click event.***
As you need to prevent the default action , so pass the event as a parameter in the callback function of jquery click handler.

As.
**(‘anchor-tag-class’).bind( ‘click’, function(event) {**

**event.preventDefault();**

Do your processing

**});**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding more of an explanation, try editing with the button bottom left of your answer